# Book: kid named Max and his best friends find a bag of magical stones in an old tree

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

The book is about a kid named Max and his three best friends, two boys and a girl. He just moved to the town and made friends with the two boys then the girl and one day they were hanging out in the forest and found a bag in an old tree. In the bag were stones that turn out to be magical.

They end up going to a school and doing stuff that no one else in the town knows.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: The premise kind of makes me think of [*Shorts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorts_(2009_film)), but they don't claim it's based off of a book, and there's no Max.